# Liferay 6.2 authentification-hook migration to Lr 7.2 fragment?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

I asked a question regarding a hook migration lr7.2 fragment but I didn't found any response form the liferay community!

This is the link

https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/118727647

Please any help is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Let me start by thanking you to link to your original post. Not many do this - but [it helps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/364505) to check if the question has been answered elsewhere. However, two issues: If you read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] and related chapters: We love complete questions here in addition to links to external sites: SO builds a repository of Q&A on top of just answering your question. And last, for the focus of SO, the question is quite broad, here we're rather going after very concrete problems. Please focus, split into multiple questions

Comment: That being said, I'm going to answer on the Liferay forums...